# I am facing an issue with the multi select dropdown

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and I am facing an issue with the multi select dropdown. I have attached the code and the screenshot for the issue. I tried to implement the multiselect dropdown and the drop-down opens on the top of the field. Please do share your comments over this issue.
Thanks

```
Expanded(
  child: DropDownMultiSelect(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0),
      fillColor: MyColors.white,
      border:new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: new BorderSide(color:MyColors.borderColor),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          const Radius.circular(0.0),
        ),
      ),
      focusColor: MyColors.red,
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: MyColors.kPrimaryColor,width: 2),
      ),
    ),
    onChanged: (List<String> x) {
      widget.volunteerPlayernamecontroller.clear();
      List<TextEditingController> name=[];
      for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        name.add(TextEditingController());
        name[i].text=x[i].toString();
      }
      widget.volunteerPlayernamecontroller.addAll(name);
      setState(() {
        selected = x;
      });
    },
    options:names,
    selectedValues: [],
    whenEmpty: 'Choose Volunteer',
  ),
),
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y60vR.png

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter